Apex SDK for Slack: Has Salesforce given up?
I am looking for any guidance/roadmap/articles on Slack Apex SDK. It looks like there are little updates to this project after 2022. There are very few examples available online:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk/guide/setup-install-app.html
https://github.com/albarivas/ready-to-fly-sdk/tree/master

I am able to send slack message from Apex. However, I am unable to format the message. For example: I would like to use fields to show record details in two columns. I tried multiple ways, I get an error (similar to below). I also would like to display a list of records with links (I could not find any documentation anywhere).
Is there any documentation anywhere on ways to map Slack Block Kit to ViewDefinition yaml file?
Error I receive when I experiment with .view file:
force-app/main/default/viewdefinitions/sObjectRecordDetails.view  Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.salesforce.platform.slack.view.model.Component>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

